# Android studio flutter app doesn't run on my android device or an emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

when i run the app nothing happens and then it just says timeout waiting for app to start

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to keep patience despite of terminate app building. i faced same issue and waited for around 15-20 minutes and finally app is install.

[image]